# Installation of DataStax DevCenter-1.3.1 failed on Windows 8

Tags: cassandra, datastax-devcenter

I get following logs when I try to install it

[image: Error Logs]

I have following Java Version
 `java version "1.8.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 25.60-b23, mixed mode, sharing)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to launch a 64 bit version of DevCenter:
`-arch x86_64`

but Java is 32 bit - note the **lack** of any 64 bit indication in your `java -version` output.

A 64-bit version of Java will report this:
`$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_40"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_40-b25)
Java HotSpot(TM)` **64-Bit** `Server VM (build 25.40-b25, mixed mode)`

I've seen this happen on Windows systems where the OS is 64-bit and a 32-bit browser is used to download Java so it defaults to downloading a 32-bit version of Java. You have to be careful to either 1) use a 64-bit version of the browser or 2) specifically select to download a 64-bit version of Java.